# Google Map Api - google map not showing properly after load second time

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am opening google map in bootstrap modal. When I click on link to open google map modal, it is showing well, after close modal if I am open google map modal second time map is not showing as open  first time check images to understand problem[image: first time open google map modal]

[image: second time open google map modal without refresh page]

please check first image,in that pullen park(one park is showing on map) is showing bottom right corner but when I open google map modal again pullen park is showing top left corner,so why pullen park is not showing same as first image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is probably due to some hiding issues. You might want to recenter your map after you do `google.maps.event.trigger(map, 'resize');`, or listen to the resize event like the following:

```
google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'resize', function() {
    console.log("resize triggered");
});
```

for more about resize:
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference

for more about event:
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/events

Answer (score 1):

simply just put

```
google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'resize', function() {
    map.setCenter(marker.getPosition());
});
```